# MVC Portal Site Architectural Considerations, Authentication & Content

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

### Scenario:

- IIS ARR front-end is distributing load to *n.* IIS app servers running MVC 6.
- Multiple domains point to the ARR
- Using MS Identity authentication
- All Appservers serve the same application with slight branding/content changes depending on which domain was used to access the site.  We'll call each variation a "portal".

### Can you verify the following assumption?

- Identity auth tickets appear to work out of the box for this scenario.

  Specifically, If a user logs into the site under "www.foo.com" and then hits the same site using "www.bar.com" that they will not appear to be authenticated at bar.com (even though they are technically hitting the same application, on the same or different App server).

  Are there any gotchas with this?

### Can you check this architectural decision?

- We've linked in a MVC 6 middleware component to inspect the domain of each request to set a "portalID" variable in the HTTP context's Request object.  The component just checks the domain name against a Hashtable and sets the appropriate portal ID for the request.
- Variable content is rendered using partial views and the new view components.  All variable content (like header image references, text, etc) is stored in a database and IMemoryCached cached and varied by portalID

  - When a user registers, the registration method tags the user with their PortalID (we only have one user DB for all "portals", but want to keep the users segmented).

**Is this a reasonable way to implement this scenario, given the new MVC 6 framework?**

**Can you think of any gotchas with this implementation?**

Answer (score 1):

In regards to authentication, auth tickets (cookie-based authentication) are per domain so you'll have no problems with a user accessing Portal A when only logged into Portal B. You *can* implement so that can be authenticated across multiple sub-domains, but that's a non-default scenario and only applies to sub-domains, not to entirely different domains. In fact, prove it to yourself by logging into one of your portals and seeing the authentication ticket in your cookie collection. Then go to another domain/portal and view your cookie collection: your auth cookie won't be there (applies to any cookie).

I've implemented scenarios like this many times without issues (one app, many different "sites" with caching/differing views/etc.) albeit Forms Authentication ones, but the principal still applies.